# .net 6 Web App Update the value of the current cookie

Tags: cookies, token, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I want to update the value of the cookie available in the browser, but I am getting the error as below. How do I update the value of the current cookie?

```
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RefreshTokenLogin([FromForm] string refreshToken)
        {
            User user = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.RefreshToken == refreshToken);
            if (user != null && user?.RefrestTokenEndDate > DateTime.Now)
            {
                TokenHandler tokenHandler = new TokenHandler(configuration);
                Token token = tokenHandler.CreateAccessToken(user);

                user.RefreshToken = token.RefreshToken;
                user.RefrestTokenEndDate = token.Expiration.AddMinutes(3);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            
                Response.Cookies["RefreshToken"].Value = _sha.Encrypt(user.RefreshToken);//the line where i got the error
               

                return Ok();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

> error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
> 'IResponseCookies'

Comment: Any update on it sir?

Comment: @TinyWang I couldn't find the update command. so i delete the same cookie first and then add it again.

Comment: What I post below doesn't work for you? Okay....

Comment: @TinyWang he did you write it :D I'll try when I get to that part again. thank you .)

Answer (score 0):

How about set the cookie again?

Firstly, I have a .net 6 api project, and I set cookie like this:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    Response.Cookies.Append("RefreshToken", "asdfgh");
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

When I call this api, there will be a cookie showing in the brower, then I call another api like this:

```
    [Route("home")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"] != null)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Append("RefreshToken", "newValue");
            }
            return "done";
        }
    }
```

Then the cookie changed to the new value.

[image]
[image]